# Is it a bad writing practice to start sentences with a verb?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

I realized I start sentences with *the*, *he*, *she*, *it*, *after* and *then* all the time. So I'm starting to use verbs instead. Here is an example of something I wrote:

> Erin left out a sigh. "Why am I thinking so much about this?"
>
> She decided to forget about the thing, and go lie on bed instead. Talking to herself had really made her tired; a little bit more
> and she would go crazy. She reached to her desk and grabbed her phone.
> Hearing Benjamin's voice would probably snap her back to reality.

I remember having read about this long ago (but I don't remember if the author considered it good or bad writing).

Comment: English sentences can only ever start with nouns or a suitable substitute. Exceptions include phrases in the imperative and certain idioms and expressions. Pronouns can, and often should, be substituted for nouns in fiction as always referring to an object by its proper name/noun gets troublesome quickly; ask the guys behind Lojban. So you can't have a problem with 'over-using' pronouns. _The structure_ might need some work and variation, but I can't help with that. What you call 'verbs' (talking-hearing-...) are gerunds or present participles, somewhat more 'nouns' than 'verbs'.

Comment: @Mussri, can you cite a source for your assertion?

Comment: @LaurenI, Which? Although now I think I should have said _"English **phrases** can only ever start with nouns or a suitable substitute."_ which might not change anything so which part do you disagree with?

Comment: @Mussri The assertion that "English phrases or sentences can only ever start with nouns or a suitable substitute." And perhaps clarify what "a suitable substitute" is. Do you think that david.smith's examples below are not English sentences?

Comment: @LaurenI, No. Smith's examples are correct but his sentences are what varied not the phrases. This's a hopeful rephrasing: what I meant to say is that English is always SVO (unlike, eg., Arabic, which supports SVO and VSO among others) and that what alex meant is structural variety which has nothing to do with proper verbs. The verbs should be near the topic of the sentence in the middle/end (even if one could do otherwise grammatically) and that focusing on using their other forms to achieve variety is undesirable as it might get formulaic. I hope I've cleared that up...

Comment: This is not incorrect but it's easy to fall into a trap with that: "Loitering around the backyard, a policeman walked up to Timmy." This is an obvious case of the screw-up, where it's obvious it was Timmy who was loitering and not the policeman. But make the sentences more complex and it becomes very easy to forget whom the verb describes. (...a classic is "spurred in the flanks hard, the countess was carried away on the back of her black mare...")

Comment: @Mussri Okay, your new comment makes sense. But saying "English is an SVO language" (which describes how the grammar functions) is NOT semantically the same as saying "English sentences must START with a noun and END with a verb" (which demands the same structure of every sentence). The former is correct. The latter is demonstrably not.

Comment: @LaurenI, I _assumed_ I'd clarified this by correcting 'sentences' to 'phrases' earlier but no. What would you call a strictly SVO construct? All English [something] are SVO modified by adjuncts/conjunctions/... which as a whole make a sentence but I'm short on vocab here.

Comment: "English is an SVO language." That doesn't affect where those items appear in the sentence in relation to other items. (I know English is not your first language; I did eventually understand you. :) )

Comment: @LaurenI, Well, if you did 'eventually' understand me then there's something very wrong in what I said, or at least horribly unclear. Should I delete my comments just in case?

Comment: @Mussri No, not at all. It's a learning process for everyone. Why remove it just because it took a while for us to understand one another? The entire comment trail is worthwhile.

Comment: @Mussri, correcting "sentences" to "phrases" makes your statement less accurate, not more, unless you're using "phrase" in a non-standard way. There are noun phrases (which begin with a noun), but also verb phrases (which begin with a verb) and prepositional phrases (which begin with a preposition), and many other types to boot. Your clarification that English is SVO is correct, but that leaves out a lot of things, especially the fact that the S does not have to be a noun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sentences should start with anything that makes grammatical and syntactical sense. Writers create, so create your own rules. As long as they make sense, your reader will understand.

Your example is actually a gerund, which does act as a noun, but consider these:

- "To be or not to be?"  (Starts with a preposition.)
- "Brilliantly, he began his sentence with a verb." (Starts with an
  adverb.)
- "Skilled and astute, he quickly posted his question on Stack
  Exchange." (Starts with an adjective.)
- "And even some sentences can start with conjunctions." (Starts with
  ... a conjunction.)

I believe that all of these are correct.

Comment: *To be or not to be* does **not** start with a preposition. It starts with an infinitive verb.

Answer (score 8):

None of your sentences start with verbs, though two of them start with *gerunds*, which is not quite the same thing. In any case, I think that you are fretting about nothing. If your sentences sound fine to you as an English speaker and they avoid the monotony that you were noticing before, then by all means write them however you want. I can't think of many things less useful for a writer than worrying about imaginary rules like "don't start with a verb".

Comment: And, never use a preposition to end a sentence with.

Comment: And it is incorrect to ever split an infinitive.

Answer (score 8):

Begin a sentence with a verb sometimes. See, I just did. Twice.

As others have noted, you're apparently confusing gerunds with verbs in your example. But that said, gerunds are perfectly good words and can be used to vary your sentence structure.

I don't know where you were told that a sentence can never begin with a verb. Imperative sentences (i.e. commands) routinely start with verbs: "Go to the store." "Bring me the book." Etc. It's relatively rare otherwise in English, as the conventional structure is subject-verb-object, but it's not unheard of. "Thinking quickly, Bob leaped for the door." "'Leaving so soon?' Sally asked." Sometimes it's effective to use a non-standard word order for emphasis or to save an unexpected word for last. "Left in the middle of the night, he did." "Kill me they might, but they will never defeat me."

If you find that you are in a rut and all your sentences follow the same pattern, then, as Tylerharms says, I would definitely make an effort to consciously break the pattern. (Now that you mention this, I have to look at my own writing and see if I've fallen into this!) Of course one should avoid the opposite extreme, of trying so hard to vary your sentence constructions that you over-use odd phrasings.

Comment: "Run away! Run away!"

Answer (score 5):

If you are struggling with variety in your sentence structure, I think you should make it a *writing exercise* to begin sentences with verbs. Then do an exercise where you begin sentences with adjectives. Then do an exercise where you begin sentences with words that rhyme with *blue*. Any and all techniques that force you out of your comfort zone and get you to practice new forms of writing are good. Ultimately, you should seek variety in your writing, but this is not something you just do. As you have found, once you get used to a certain organizational structure, you start thinking that way. Other sentence constructions have to become comfortable to you before you can start implementing them effectively. So, while the simple advice is to just unfetter yourself, the hard truth is that it's going to seem like you're writing gibberish until new writing constructions feel natural.

Answer (score 0):

Every word, and how you use it are tools in your toolbox. You can follow proper grammar, or twist it to barely understandable, and these are still just tools.

What happens when you start your sentences with verbs? What is that tool used for?

The verb is the meat of the sentence. It's the most important word in the sentence. In fact if you don't have one, then you have a fragment. Other words in the sentence just describe the verb. Who is doing, the action, how is the action being done. Other even less important words describe the actors who are doing the action. The more flowery the writing, the more words you have besides the verb.

So now let's think about starting with verbs. We are jumping straight to the most important part. We don't have time to waste with other words. This makes the writing feel fast, direct, intense, personal. If those are the things you want, start with a verb. If they are not, then surround the verb with other words to give it the feeling that you need.

As always writing is best when it has ups and down. Sentences should be of varied lengths, and structure. You can't use any one tool for the whole piece of writing. Use many tools to create something interesting and changing, where the grammar itself is part of telling the story.

Answer (score -1):

I have pondered on this question for some time. My conclusion is this: providing the sentence makes sense to the writer and the reader, using the verb or the subject to open a sentence is fine. I don't agree with those who say that the subject should always come first. Writers are creative people. Rules are there for a reason, of course. It's redundant prepositions that writers need to be more aware of, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't think 'the grammar police' will come after you - several other answers to this question have already pointed out that sentences can start with many different parts of speech.

Comment: This adds nothing to the existing answers.